# Saving to database inside loop

Tags: java, database, spring-data

i wanted to insert some test data in my database, so i looped save method. But it only saves it 1 time. Can you explain why?

Here is my controller method with my loop:

```
@PostMapping("")
public Long save(@RequestBody Car car) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        System.out.println("??");
        carService.save(car);
    }
    Car savedCar = carService.save(car);
    return savedCar.getId();
}
```

carService:

```
@Override
public Car save(Car car) {
    return carRepository.save(car);
}
```

carRepository:

```
public interface CarRepository extends CrudRepository<Car, Long> {
    List<Car> findAll();
    Car getCarById(Long id);
}
```

Comment: It's always the same object. What did you expect?

Comment: Also, please note, that SQL Inserts within a loop is always a bad idea. Use batch statements instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It saves it 1 time because you are saving 100 times the same `Car` object. No changes are detected and there is no need to refresh the persistent state of the object.

Before the first save operation, the `car` instance is just a value object, in the sense that, it has not yet a persistent state. This means that there is no `id` is associated to the `value object`. After the first save is done, `car` now has an identifier associated with it. At each consecutive save this `id` is used to identify the object, as no changes are done, it is not necessary to perform any changes in the database.

Answer (score 1):

Because the save method of Spring data -jpa is to save and update for both . Once you save the data it save it in db properly by creating new row , but second time you again save the same data . Spring-data-jpa finds the same data so it just update the same row and do no create new row

Comment: but i have autogenerated Id, so when i save it to database, second save shoulnd't have new id? I am not passing ID, so normally it should create a new one.

Comment: Since your object has been just saved in database it is as persistence instance .  **A persistent instance has a representation in the database and an identifier value. It might just have been saved or loaded, however, it is by definition in the scope of a Session. Hibernate will detect any changes made to an object in persistent state and synchronize the state with the database when the unit of work completes.** ......Hope it will clear

Answer (score 0):

When you save in database using `Hibernate` passing the referency object automatically the id is setted in the object, so when you save again it´s only editing the object.
If you want so save change the id to `0`.

```
@PostMapping("")
public Long save(@RequestBody Car car) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
         System.out.println("??");
         car.setId(0);
         carService.save(car);
    }
    Car savedCar = carService.save(car);
    return savedCar.getId();
  }
```